# Why are there different return types in TensorFlow for the same operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I have two constant nodes:

```
>> node1 = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
>> node2 = tf.constant(4.0)
```

When I run this graph in Jupyter Notebook, the return types are different for following two session runs:

```
>> sess = tf.Session()
```

For this operation, there is no output cell:

```
>> print(sess.run(node1))# prints 3.0, but NOT in the output cell; output cell missing
#prints 3.0
```

But when I run the session as:

```
>> print(sess.run(node1)), print(sess.run(node2)) #prints 3.0 and on the next line, it prints 4.0, and it ALSO prints a tuple (None, None) in the output cell.
```

Can someone please explain the return types of these?
[image: Jupyter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second line has two `print` statements separated by commas. The `print` function returns `None`, and a single `None` is ignored by the Python REPL (read-eval-print loop). However, the comma creates a tuple, which is not ignored even when it contains only `None` values.

If you want to run multiple statements on a single line, use `;` instead of `,`:

```
print("foo"); print("bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

### You're creating a tuple

print is a function just like any other. It doesn't return a value, so it returns None, which is not generally shown.

However, the comma operator creates a tuple, and jupyter shows the returned value.

Writing 4,4 would result in (4,4).

Writing None,None would result in what you're seeing.

If you simply want to execute two operations, put them each in their own line - the comma is not for that.